# PDF printer without user intervention

Tags: .net, pdf, printing

I'm looking for a PDF printer that doesn't ask the user to choose a filename and directory, but simply saves it to a predefined folder with a unique filename.

Thx.

Comment: This should be on Superuser.com.

Answer (score 1):

The [PDFsharp](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/) .Net libraries allow you to create PDF documents without user intervention, and the [`System.IO.Path.GetTempFilename()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) function can give you a unique filename to write out to (though I think it appends a .tmp extension which you may want to change)

Answer (score 0):

A PDF printer is normally just a print driver.  It's up to individual applications what dialogs they will display.  You could always write your own program that doesn't prompt users.